# Calculate number of strings

Tags: algorithms

Given a string S how many different strings can be formed by erasing a sigle letter from the given string?

EXAMPLE : "ABA"
Returns: 3
The following three Strings are possible in this case: "BA", "AA", "AB".

EXAMPLE 2 : "AABACCCCABAA"
Returns: 7

Comment: Because you cannot distinguish (see Ex.2) between erasing the first A and erasing the second A, the solution will be a function of the number of "blocks" into the string, where a block is a substring formed by $n$ (with $n \ge 1$) occurrences of the same letter. So, if the number of "blocks" in the initial string is $n$, you will have $n$ possible results.

Comment: You are basically counting runs of a single character. In the second example, removing either one of the C's generates the same string, similarly, removing either one of the first two A's generates the same string.

Answer (score 0):

If you interpret your string as a char-array and two consecutive char are different, you have one more possible result.

In pseudo-code it would look somehow like this:

```
 count = 1
 for (s=1..string.length-1)
   if(charAt[s]== charAt[s-1]
      count += 1
   end if
 end for
 return count
```

---

For your second example:

> EXAMPLE 2 : "AABACCCCABAA" Returns: 7

- Start with count = 1
- A == A: count=1
- B != A: count=2
- A != B: count=3
- C != A: count=4
- C == C: count=4
- C == C: count=4
- C == C: count=4
- A != C: count=5
- B != A: count=6
- A != B: count=7
- A == A: count=7
- return 7

Comment: explain by above example.I think its wrong

Comment: I made an edit.